# How do I match exact word boundary, but excluding special characters in front and back?

Tags: regex, tcl, word-boundary

I want the regex in tcl to match my specified word boundary, without any special characters such as `+-.()` in front or back.

Here are the things I tried and it just doesn't match properly:

Let's say I have the following string:

```
hello world +hello world -hello world hello+ hello
```

I want it to only match `hello`, not `hello+` or `-hello`.

```
\bhello\b
```

- `hello`
- `+hello`
- `-hello`
- `hello+`

```
[^+-]\bhello\b[^+-]
```

- no matches

```
[^+-]\bhello\b
```

- (doesn't match the first `hello` even though it should've matched)
- `hello+`
- `hello`

```
(?![+-])\bhello\b(?![+-])
```

- `hello`
- `+hello`
- `-hello`

Comment: Pehaps using a capturing group `(?:^|[^-+.()])(hello)(?![-+.()])` https://regex101.com/r/rwrvs9/1

Answer (score 2):

As [documented](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm), Tcl uses `\y` to match a word boundary, not `\b` (which is a backspace character for compatibility with the escapes used by general Tcl code). This means you need an RE something like this:

```
(?:^|[^-+])\yhello\y(?:$|[^-+])
```

The middle piece is `\yhello\y` which matches the word, and then we need `^|[^-+]` at the beginning to match either the beginning of the string or a character other than `-` or `+`, and equivalently `$|[^-+]` for the end. (I put those in `(?:…)` just to limit the scope of the `|` RE operator.)

Demonstrating from an interactive session:

```
% set RE {(?:^|[^-+])\yhello\y(?:$|[^-+])}
(?:^|[^-+])\yhello\y(?:$|[^-+])
% regexp $RE "hello"
1
% regexp $RE "ahello"
0
% regexp $RE "+hello"
0
% regexp $RE "+ hello"
1
% regexp $RE "hello+"
0
% regexp $RE "hello-"
0
% regexp $RE "hello.-"
1
```

Comment: The following constraint could be done with a lookahead constraint, but Tcl's RE engine doesn't support lookbehind constraints so we still need to have bits other than the central piece in the main RE match.

Answer (score 1):

This regex matches the word hello, allows spaces before and after, but doesn't allow anything else. Creating a boundary of word characters AND special characters.

```
(?<!\S)hello(?!\S)
```

This uses the "negative look-ahead" and "negative look-behind" syntax.

`(?<!\S)`: Look behind and make sure there aren't any non-whitespace characters.

`(?!\S)`: Look ahead and make sure there aren't any non-whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

Another option instead of using a word boundary, is to exclude matching a word char in the negated character class together with the other characters that should not be matched:

```
(?:^|[^-+.()\w])(hello)(?![-+.()\w])
```

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `^` Start of string
  - `|` Or
  - `[^-+.()\w]` Negated character class `[^`, match any char except the listed
- `)` Close non capture group
- `(hello)` Capture group 1, match hello
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is not

  - `[-+.()\w]` Match any of the listed
- `)` Close lokahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8pWa09/1)